# Embed Bokeh server with multiple roots in Django

Tags: django, bokeh

I have a bokeh app with multiple roots. Inside the bokeh template, I use

```
{{embed(roots.plot1)}}
{{embed(roots.plot2)}}
# etc
```

to load the plots. This works fine. Now, I'd like to get the plots to load inside a web page I'll be serving from a Django app. Since my plots are generated using Holoviews, the Bokeh server is essential.

The bokeh documentation https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples has examples of how to autoload all plots from a Bokeh server, and it also has examples of how to embed multiple static plots using `components()`, but none of these seem to cover this use case.

Here's what I've tried:

```
# The following function is a function-based Django view
def django_view(request):

    bokeh_url = 'http://localhost:5006/experiment'
    roots = {root.name: root for root in session.document.roots}

    with pull_session(url=bokeh_url) as session:

        # I was hoping that these will generate separate autoload scripts for each model.
        # Unfortunately they each embed all the models.
        script1 = server_session(session_id=session.id, url=bokeh_url, model=roots['plot1'])
        script2 = server_session(session_id=session.id, url=bokeh_url, model=roots['plot2'])

    return render(request, "template.html", {"script1": script1, "script2: script2})
```

Excerpt from template.html:

```
{{ script1 | safe }}
{{ script2 | safe }}
```

The result is that each script tag loads all the plots on top of eachother. How can I get each plot embedded exactly once, where I want it? How should I be doing this?